# Coded UI - custom property

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am working on a Coded UI project with [code first approach](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/what-is-code-first.aspx), and I ran into a situation where an element that I am interested in does not have an "ID" property, but "data-id" property instead.

How would I be able to fire up Mouse.Click() on the "Original" link in the  example below:

```html
<div class="not-unique" data-uid="93fdb678-2d04-4543-b129-e146453704e6">
    <div class="editor-row">
        <div>
            <ul>            
                <li><a id="dwnOriginal_247" href="">Original</a></li>
                <li><a id="dwnOriginal_247" href="">Error</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you using cuite , uimap or selenium?

Comment: What's code first? anyway - since both li has the same id you could invoke "FindMatchingControls()" on the controls defenition and than pick the one you wanna click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom property if you set your locator like this:

```
public HtmlHyperlink originalLink()
{
    HtmlHyperlink target = new HtmlHyperlink(browser);
    target.SearchProperties["customId"] = "dwnOriginal_247";
    // and then find the Original link using InnerText
    target.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlHyperlink.PropertyNames.InnerText, "Original");
    return target;
}
```

Then, you can simply call back to originalLink() for your click:

```
mouse.Click(originalLink());
```